# How to write for loop to take property from object and insert it in function javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I am beginner in programming and I wish someone help me on this code.

My code is:-

```
var i = Object.keys(mws.Result.InventorySupplyList.member).length
console.log(i)
a0 = mws.Result.InventorySupplyList.member[0].ASIN
a1 = mws.Result.InventorySupplyList.member[1]
const amazonScraper = require('amazon-buddy');
(async () => {
    try {
        // Get single product details by using ASIN id
        const product_by_asin_0 = await amazonScraper.asin({ asin: a0 });
        console.log(product_by_asin_0)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
(async () => {
    try {
       // Get single product details by using ASIN id
        const product_by_asin_1 = await amazonScraper.asin({ asin: a0 });
        console.log(product_by_asin_1)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

mws is JOSN object

```
const mws = {
    "ResponseMetadata": {
      "RequestId": "e8698ffa-8e59-11df-9acb-230ae7a8b736"
    },
    "Result": {
      "InventorySupplyList": {
        "member": [
          {
            "SellerSKU": "SampleSKU1",
            "ASIN": "B00000K3CQ",
            "TotalSupplyQuantity": "20",
            "FNSKU": "X0000000FM",
            "Condition": "NewItem",
            "SupplyDetail": {},
            "InStockSupplyQuantity": "15",
            "EarliestAvailability": {
              "TimepointType": "Immediately"
            }
          },
          {
            "SellerSKU": "SampleSKU2",
            "ASIN": "B00004RWQR",
            "TotalSupplyQuantity": "0",
            "FNSKU": "X00008FZR1",
            "Condition": "UsedLikeNew",
            "SupplyDetail": {},
            "InStockSupplyQuantity": "0"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Headers": {
      "x-mws-quota-max": "",
      "x-mws-quota-remaining": "",
      "x-mws-quota-resetson": "",
      "x-mws-timestamp": "2018-09-05T06:13:00.276Z",
      "content-type": "text/xml",
      "content-charset": "",
      "content-length": "",
      "content-md5": "",
      "date": ""
    },
    "StatusCode": 200
  }
```

I want to take the ASIN from the mws object and insert it in the other code which will scrape the details from amazon.com , as you notice already that I figured out the object mws has 2 ASIN and did insert it manually in the scraper. If you can help me how to write for loop to do the code in what ever ASINs.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const amazonScraper = require('amazon-buddy');
const requests = Promise.all(
    Object.keys(mws["Result"]["InventorySupplyList"]["member"])
          .map (member => amazonScraper.asin({ asin: member["ASIN"] }))
)
requests.then(responces => console.log(responces))
```